# ListView blocking Admob Ad

Tags: java, android, listview, admob

I have the following XML file which corresponds to a ListActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/classview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxx" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I call this Java code from within the ListActivity:

```
public void setupAd(){
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice("xxxx");
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


}
```

When I look at the graphical layout of my XML file, it seems to neatly have the ad banner on top of the ListView. However, when I run my actual app, the ListView seems to take up the entire screen, likely blocking the ad. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: have you tried loading a real add with real id?

Comment: your `xml` is correct, this could be due to the ads are not loading up! do you have `internet` *permission* in your **manifest**?

Comment: Sure it is not just been loaded yet. First time it may take some minutes before the first ad appears, and until the it does not take any space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your ListView has layout_height="fill_parent".

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
 />
```

Instead have it wrap_content and use layout_weight="1" to tell it to consume any unused space.